# Radio buttons don't apply CSS on check

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create two radio buttons that change color once the user selects them. However, once I select one of them they don't apply the supposed CSS:

```css
.poller-nature-radio input[type="radio"] {
    opacity: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 0;
}

#id_poller_nature label {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #ddd;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-family: sans-serif, Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: 2px solid #444;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

#id_poller_nature {
    display: flex;
}

#id_poller_nature li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

#id_poller_nature input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    background-color:#bfb;
    border-color: #4c4;
}
```

```html
<div class="fieldWrapper poller-nature-radio">
  <label for="id_poller_nature_0">Nothing changes on select:</label>
  <ul id="id_poller_nature">
<li><label for="id_poller_nature_0"><input type="radio" name="poller_nature" value="Choice 1" required="" id="id_poller_nature_0">
    Question</label>

</li>
<li><label for="id_poller_nature_1"><input type="radio" name="poller_nature" value="Choice 2" required="" id="id_poller_nature_1">
    Information</label>

</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you used `+` css selector, the label should come as a sibling and come after the input. Check the below snippet.

```css
.poller-nature-radio input {
    position: fixed;
    visibility: hidden;
}

#id_poller_nature label {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #ddd;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-family: sans-serif, Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: 2px solid #444;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

#id_poller_nature {
    display: flex;
}

#id_poller_nature li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

#id_poller_nature input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    background-color:#bfb;
    border-color: #4c4;
}
```

```html
<div class="fieldWrapper poller-nature-radio">
  <label for="id_poller_nature_0">Click the button to see the change:</label>
  <ul id="id_poller_nature">
    <li>
      <input
        type="radio"
        name="poller_nature"
        value="Choice 1"
        required=""
        id="id_poller_nature_0"
      />
      <label for="id_poller_nature_0"> Question</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input
        type="radio"
        name="poller_nature"
        value="Choice 2"
        required=""
        id="id_poller_nature_1"
      />
      <label for="id_poller_nature_1"> Information</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: is there an alternative to swapping the html elements? I am using Python/Django to render the html, so I cant change the order

Comment: Mm., it won't work the way you posted, because the label is the parent of input in the question. There is no way to select a parent from child in css. So

Answer (score 0):

```
    .poller-nature-radio input[type="radio"] {
    opacity: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 0;
}

#id_poller_nature label {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #ddd;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-family: sans-serif, Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: 2px solid #444;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

#id_poller_nature {
    display: flex;
}

#id_poller_nature li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

#id_poller_nature_1:checked  {
    background-color:#bfb;
    border-color: #4c4;
}
<div class="fieldWrapper poller-nature-radio">
  <label for="id_poller_nature_0">Nothing changes on select:</label>
  <ul id="id_poller_nature">
  <li><label for="id_poller_nature_0"><input type="radio" name="poller_nature" 
 value="Choice 1" required="" id="id_poller_nature_0">
    Question</label>

</li>
<li><label for="id_poller_nature_1"><input type="radio" name="poller_nature" value="Choice 2" required="" id="id_poller_nature_1">
    Information</label>

</li>
  </ul>
</div>

Try to access the input element using the individual id then handle the :check state
```

Comment: there's no individual ID

Comment: Okay, I see in the code, there is `<input type="radio" name="poller_nature" 
 value="Choice 1" required="" id="id_poller_nature_0">` I think you can use the id=`id_pollar_nature_0` or use a class  in input to handle the :clic, Check styling section of this mdn article https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML like this.

```
         <ul id="id_poller_nature">
           <li>
              <input type="radio" name="poller_nature" value="Choice 1" required="" id="id_poller_nature_0">
              <label for="id_poller_nature_0">`enter code 
here`Question</label>
</li>
```